# How to implement badge using push notification in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am writing an application in android. We will have dashboard with multiple icons and I want to show badge on one of the icon with counter number. I want implementation such like counter number will get updated on dashboard once notification comes. How can I achieve it on notification.

Here is a deal,

We have a table in which we are inserting the data from user using cloud (i.e. Google App Engine). Once entries get inserted into table push notification should prompt user and counter number on dashboard will get updated being on same screen. 
Please give me an example so I can implement it into my application.

Thanks,
Prashant.

Comment: Are you getting notification?

Comment: On your receive method of notification, put code from this link https://github.com/shafty023/SamsungBadger.

Answer (score 1):

You want to apply badge for the application as iOS?
If you want to do that, there is no direct approach from android since it is not behavior of android but still we can do with the help of the few manufactures like Samsung, sony and HTC.

Look for more details [android-ios-style-badge-app-icon-for.html](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/07/android-ios-style-badge-app-icon-for.html)

Answer (score -1):

I have Required similar kind of Functionality i have achieved this using following code

menu/main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourappname="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:title="@string/notifications"
        yourappname:actionLayout="@layout/notification_update_count"
        yourappname:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

layout/notification_update_count.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <!-- Menu Item Image -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notification_bell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_actionbar_notification" />

    <!-- Badge Count -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/notification_bell"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/notification_bell"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

src/MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = MainActivity.this;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (currentPosition != 6 && currentPosition != 7 && currentPosition != 8 && currentPosition != 9) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            item = menu.findItem(R.id.notification);
            View menu_notification_view = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
            ImageView notification_bell = (ImageView) menu_notification_view.findViewById(R.id.notification_bell);
            try {
                TextView notification_count = (TextView) menu_notification_view.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
                if (Count > 0) {
                    notification_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    notification_count.setText(String.valueOf(Count));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```